# CSS file is not generated when using vue build and tailwindcss

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css, vue-cli

I am building a component library using Vue and TailwindCSS. When I pulled in the dependancy and loaded in the components to my application I noticed non of the styles were present.

I went back to the build and could see that the `common`, `umd` and `umd.min` files were generated but the css file was not.

If I add something like

```
<style>
.foo {}
</style>
```

To one of my component vue files and run the build command I can see the `/dist/libname.css` file is generated with `.foo{}` inside.

Is there anything I need to do to get the purged css to be included in the build?

Comment: Your vue.config file has `css: { extract: false }`?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't actually find an answer so I came up with a solution that might be well overcomplicating it.

I have the following scripts in my package.json file;

```
"build": "npm run build-vue && npm run tailwind && node uibuild",
"build-vue": "vue-cli-service build --target lib --name mypackagename ./src/index.js",
"tailwind": "NODE_ENV=production tailwindcss build -o ./dist/mypackagename-base.css"
```

And a javascript file;

```
const fs = require("fs");
const version = require('./package.json').version;
const packageName = 'mypackagename';

fs.readFile("./dist/" + packageName + "-base.css", (err, buff) => {
    let contents = "/** \n" +
        "* Some Intro Title \n" +
        "* Version: v" + version + "\n" +
        "* Author: John Doe \n" +
        "*/\n\n";

    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }
    contents += buff.toString() + "\n";

    fs.readFile("./dist/" + packageName + ".css", (err, buff) => {
        if (! err) contents += buff.toString();
        fs.writeFile("./dist/" + packageName + ".prod.css", contents, err => {
            if (err) console.error(err);
            if (fs.existsSync("./dist/" + packageName + "-base.css")) fs.unlinkSync("./dist/" + packageName + "-base.css");
            if (fs.existsSync("./dist/" + packageName + ".css")) fs.unlinkSync("./dist/" + packageName + ".css");
        });

    });
});
```

and then simply run `npm run build`